# Sum of Elapsed Time in minute-by-minute data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data that is gathered minute by minute. It looks like this (this is just an extract):

```
id      tstamp              name    elapsed_time    reason
54945   2014-03-26 15:09:02 foobar  00:02:02        6
54845   2014-03-26 15:08:02 foobar  00:01:02        6
54775   2014-03-26 15:07:02 foobar  00:06:02        9
54711   2014-03-26 15:06:02 foobar  00:05:02        9
54647   2014-03-26 15:05:02 foobar  00:04:01        9
54583   2014-03-26 15:04:02 foobar  00:03:01        9
54519   2014-03-26 15:03:02 foobar  00:02:01        9
54455   2014-03-26 15:02:02 foobar  00:01:00        9
54375   2014-03-26 15:01:02 foobar  00:57:38        6
54311   2014-03-26 15:00:02 foobar  00:56:38        6
54246   2014-03-26 14:59:02 foobar  00:55:37        6
54182   2014-03-26 14:58:02 foobar  00:54:37        6
```

I would like to calculate how much time a certain "name" has been on a certain code (reason). Someone can be on a certain code at different moments in time, and can go back to a previous code  whenever they want, in which case the elapsed_time would be reset.

I thought a simple SQL query would get the job done, so I tried:

```
SELECT agent_name, tstamp, reason, elapsed_time
    FROM rtv_data 
    WHERE DATE(tstamp) = DATE(CURDATE()) AND agent_name = 'foobar'
    GROUP BY reason
```

But the results aren't as expected:

```
name    tstamp              reason  elapsed_time
foobar  2014-03-26 14:03:25 6       00:00:11
foobar  2014-03-26 12:54:40 9       03:51:22
```

I've tried researching the topic on time series. Apparently, this could be solved using a  self-join, but since I'm fairly new to SQL, I just can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want precision down to the second? If not, you could just do a COUNT(1) grouped by name and reason, which will give you essentially the number of minutes the agent spent on each reason.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Something like this should get you  what you want `SELECT name, reason, sum(TIME_TO_SEC(elapsed_time)) as total_seconds_elapsed ... GROUP BY name, reason`

Comment: Also, is this your database schema? Can you modify how the data is stored?

Comment: @JeremyCook  : That won't get him the right answer, as his "elapsed_ time" field is not summable, it's a running total already (55 minutes, 56 minutes, 57 minutes ...)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
- No, there's no need to have the precision to the second. I tried the COUNT(1) line, but I don't see how that helps me any more than the GROUP BY line already does. Could you please expand on this?
- JeremyCook thank you for your answer, but as KyleHale said, the elapsed_time field is not summable. Only the last lines before the code switch are summable.
- Yes, this is the DB schema, and yes, I can modify how the data is stored. This is the way the data is presented and gathered, though. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I think I see where you were going when you asked about the database schema. Updating the elapsed time only if the code has not changed would help to solve this issue.